# Data binding with text input doesn't work when using `ng-if` in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created an Angular directive (see [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qE3RZMYcoNKvPZ5rmXhQ?p=preview)) as follows:

JS:

```
angular.module('plunker', []);

angular.module('plunker').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myInputs = {
    email: "test@test.org"
  }
  $scope.logToConsole = function() {
    console.log($scope.myInputs.email);
  }
});

angular.module('plunker').directive('myEmail', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      myngmodel: '='
    },
    template: '<input type="email" ng-if="true" ng-model="myngmodel" />'
  };
});
```

It's called from HTML like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <my-email myngmodel="myInputs.email"></my-email>
    <input type="button" value="log to console!" ng-click="logToConsole()">
</body>
```

The issue is as follows:

When I don't put `ng-if="true"`, in the template's textinput, or I use `ng-show` instead, the binding works correctly.

But when `ng-if="true"` is present, the binding no longer works; when I edit the field and click button, the old value is always is written to console.

- Is it a bug or works as designed?
- Is the issue due to `ng-model="myngmodel"` not following "the dot rule"?
- If so, how could I rewrite the directive so that I can pass the data model entry from outside world in the same spirit?

Comment: I'm not sure why it works the way it does, but I have had similar timing issues between ng-if and ng-model.  My solution was to wrap the input with another tag, and put the ng-if on that tag, rather than directly on the input.  I was never able to figure out why they didn't play well together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-if` creates a child scope - that's the reason why it happens. Here the quote from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

> The scope created within ngIf inherits from its parent scope using prototypal inheritance. An important implication of this is if ngModel is used within ngIf to bind to a javascript primitive defined in the parent scope. In this case any modifications made to the variable within the child scope will override (hide) the value in the parent scope.

So, when you modify the value in your input box - the new value is written to the child scope that inherits the directive's isolated scope:

```
<my-email myngmodel="myInputs.email" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <input type="email" ng-if="true" ng-model="myngmodel" class="ng-scope">
</my-email>
```

The `MainCtrl` scope var is not updated because it is bound to the directive's isolated scope var - not to its child scope.

The workaround is to use the dot notation - to make sure `ng-model` reads from and writes to the parent isolated scope of the directive:

directive's template:

```
<input type="email" ng-if="true" ng-model="myngmodel.email" />
```

binding to the outer scope:

```
<my-email myngmodel="myInputs"></my-email>
```